# Screencasting/recording in Ubuntu with pan and zoom

Tags: accessibility, screencast, zooming, kazam, desktop-recording

I want to be able to zoom in to a window (say terminal) while recording my screen in such a way that the recorder video is not "shaky" (doesn't follow mouse when zoomed in)

Something like [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vofeTuDMx-U).

How can I do this in newer versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is available through compiz. Install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run:

```
ccsm &
```

Scroll down to **accessibility** and enable **enhanced zoom desktop**. Then click on this plugin to set the default settings.

**Button 1** is the left click mouse button and **Button 3** is the right click mouse button.

Also, you probably want to set the **zoom factor** to **3**.

I set the keybinding to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to zoom in and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to zoom back out and it functions just about like it does in the video.

Also, I set the **invoke zoom box button** to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>button 1</kbd> (left click).

Then, to restrict the movement of the zoomed area or to "lock" the position, go to the **zoom area movement** tab and set **toggle zoom lock area to something like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

After you zoom in and then lock the area, you must unlock the area before you can zoom back out.

Example:

Zoom in and lock :

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> ➜ <kbd>X</kbd>

Unlock and zoom back out:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> ➜ <kbd>C</kbd>